# How do I make my script work only in specific rows?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an automated time stamp script that works when clicking a checkbox, a time stamp is populated in the cell next to it. How do I make my script work on certain rows?

*Example:* **Column C** has check boxes, **Column D** is populated with dates when Check boxes are marked.

**What I want my TimeStamp script to do:**
Work only on Row 11, all the way down.

```html
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 3;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, 1];
var SHEETNAME = 'Training Dash'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if (selectedCell.getColumn() >= COLUMNTOCHECK && selectedCell.getColumn() % 2 == 1) {
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]); 
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just posted it, just realized I forgot that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, this should help.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (selectedCell.getColumn() >= COLUMNTOCHECK && selectedCell.getColumn() % 
  2 == 1 && selectedCell.getRow() > 10) {
    var dateTimeCell = 
    selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]); 
    dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello @JPV, thank you for the reply. It seems to be working and my automation seems to be working like normal. A few questions.
<br/>
Does the '>10' mean that the automation of my script will only work from row 10 all the way down and not affect other rows above it?
<br/>
For future manipulation, would I just change '>10' to any row number I desire?

Comment: @FeatherDuster. Do you mean that your script is now working as intended? If so, please accept the answer (or upvote). And... a 'YES' to all your questions. ;-)

Comment: Actually, it's working. What you provided is working excellently. Thank you for your analysis on this. It is working as intended, nothing above the desired row is affected by the script and only affecting below my desired row. Much is appreciated.

Comment: Ok. Glad to hear. See here to learn how to accept answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers